# How to capture event when jar's command prompt is closed using X button?

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, command-prompt

I have multiple jars that communicate to single app to provide their responses.
I need to handle a scenario when command prompts are closed using X button at the top. All apps are written in JAVA so java code is needed.

I have already added shutdown hooks but they are triggered only when threads are stopped in careful manner.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {}
});
```

Also what if jars crashes how they can be captured in java?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible in Java. Different OS have different solution for that.

Ask about your OS in related site.